Aggregation in Apache Beam with and without using Schemas
I have a list of json objects in a file, see example json below:
{"user_id": "xyz", "num_bytes": 500, "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "http_request": "\"GET ehello.html HTTP/1.0\"", "http_response": 200}

I want to group by the user_id and perform various aggregations, so an example result looks like below (all sample codes are in python):
{"user_id": "xyz", "count": 1000, "total_bytes": 1000, "max_bytes": 500, "min_bytes": 100}

Using schemas, the code looks below (just specifying the aggregation code here):
...
| 'PerUserAggregations' >> beam.GroupBy('user_id')
                                      .aggregate_field('user_id', CountCombineFn(), 'count')
                                      .aggregate_field('num_bytes', sum, 'total_bytes')
                                      .aggregate_field('num_bytes', max, 'max_bytes')
                                      .aggregate_field('num_bytes', min, 'min_bytes')
                                      .with_output_types(PerUserAggregation)

class PerUserAggregation(typing.NamedTuple):
    user_id: str
    count: int
    total_bytes: int
    max_bytes: int
    min_bytes: int

Without using Schemas, I could think of first grouping by the user_id and then iterating over the values per user in a ParDo like below:
...
| 'group by user id' >> beam.GroupBy(lambda x: x["user_id"])
| 'aggregate using par do' >> beam.ParDo(MyAggregation())

class MyAggregation(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    vals = element[1]
    count = 0
    total_bytes = 0
    max_bytes = 0
    min_bytes = float('inf')
    for val in vals:
        count+= 1
        total_bytes += val["num_bytes"]
        max_bytes = max_bytes if max_bytes > val["num_bytes"] else val["num_bytes"]
        min_bytes = min_bytes if min_bytes < val["num_bytes"] else val["num_bytes"]
    dict = {"user_id": element[0], "count": count, "total_bytes": total_bytes, "max_bytes": max_bytes, "min_bytes": min_bytes}
    yield dict

My questions are below:

for the option without using Schema, are there better ways than the one I have mentioned?
for the one with Schema, what is the actual logic being used, is it just a syntactical sugar, or is the processing fundamentally different than the one where no Schema is used

